# Interweaving A and E (e.g., æ) in written words

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling, linguistics

New to this particular community.

My question relates to the word *propaedeutic*. In particular, I have witnessed the "a" interwoven with "e" to produce *propædeutic*. I once read that this is an example of a diphthong. Is the æ glyph simply used to denote a difference in pronunciation? Could anyone shed light on the roots of this linguistic practice?

And, if I may, why is propaedeutic, or propedeutic more generally, not recognized as a word when written out in this context?

Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called ***ligatures***, when two letters are tied together in a special way.

The older custom of doing so in typeset Modern English text for certain combinations of A+E or O+E no longer holds, so you should today just leave them separated except when citing an older passage verbatim.

In [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/33675/8859) that now resides on one of our sister sites, I previously wrote:

> If push comes to shove, a **reasonable *general* rule** is:
>
> - Use explicit ***lexical* ligatures** only for the things that make sense in the language you’re writing in, such as *Æ, æ* in Icelandic or Old English and *Œ, œ* in French.
> - Leave the selection of ***typographic* ligatures** to the software, which  should happen automatically for those situations where it would not look right without them.

Our word *ligature* comes from the Latin first declension noun *ligātūra*, which was in turn derived from the Latin verb *ligāre* meaning to bind. It’s a tie.

As for why something is “not recognized as a word” when written with a ligature, that’s a defect of whatever spellchecking software you’re being subjected to.

Comment: [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281527/use-of-ligatures-such-as-%c3%a6-and-%c5%93-in-english) is a duplicate. The fact that it was wrongly closed (the other question involved specifies 'in typesetting', unlike this one) notwithstanding. I trust I CV-d at the closed thread for POB reasons.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Got it, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for duplicate inquiries. By the way, propaedeutic is _not_ recognized as a word on this forum with—or without—a ligature.

Comment: @Tom That “not recognized” thing is a function of your web browser, not of this site.  Certainly [the OED recognizes it (behind its paywall)](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/152600), which is enough for most of us. :) *A subject or course of study which forms an introduction to or preparation for an art or science, or to more advanced study.*

Comment: @tchrist I see. I got caught in the weeds with that one. Also, once a question is dubbed a duplicate, is it eventually deleted? Can I mark my question as answered here?

Comment: @Tom Yes, you can mark it as answered, and no, duplicates are not deleted as a matter of course. Furthermore,  having an answer marked by the asker as helpful blocks the only low level cleanup mechanism that might otherwise do so.

Answer (score 2):

In English, the ae ligature (*Æ/æ*) is simply a typographic variant of *ae*, and generally does not signal anything different about pronunciation vs. the separate letters; in American usage, words that use *ae* (or, historically, *æ*) are often (*but not always*) respelled to use *e* instead of *ae*. See [Wikipedia on Æ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86#English).

Answer (score 1):

Usage changes with time, starting with Latin diphthongs. Œconomics -> Oeconomics -> Economics.  Generally, the US is further along in this transformation than the UK.

Of course there are other ligatures for common combinations (like fi fl etc.) which have nothing to do with Latin diphthongs. Here is a picture from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature):
[image: fi fl]